# How To Get Past Darkfall Cave?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am at the quest "Retrieve Auriel's Bow". I met the last of the Snow Elfs Knight-Paladin Gelebor. He tasked me to go through this portal to get through the Darkfall cave to the Forgotten Vale.

My local map says I am still in the cave.

And it is really dark, I keep retracing my footsteps and keep falling into the waterfall all the time all over. I have my torch lit and my candlelight spell active all throughout.

The guides on the Internet (UESP) keep saying follow the pink flowers. They lower themselves as soon as you are in proximity, and rise again.

I am really stuck here people. How to get through this cave and onto the next wayshrine?

Comment: Do you see the pink flowers?

Comment: I doubt that very much, going from one area to another is one of the few things that works fairly reliably in Gamebryo games. If you are on pc, you can use `coc DLC1DarkfallCave01` to make sure you are in the correct location.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: that cave was one of the few places I relied heavily on my khajit's night vision power.

Comment: @desaivv - mark his answer as the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost certainly in the right location and simply lost. Torches/night eye/light spells and a lot of attention may help you to find your way. The Clairvoyance spell may be helpful too, though it can sometimes fail (make sure you only have the relevant quest tracked in your journal). If you believe you are actually somewhere else, you can use the following console command on PC to teleport to Darkfall Cave: `coc DLC1DarkfallCave01`.